# How to add row in between two rows in datagridview in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have an application that include a 'datagridview' that use to type the contents directly. 
It appears like a notepad.

Right now I need a solution that I want to add a row in between two already added/typed rows. Please help me to find the solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `DataGridView.Rows.Insert(int rowIndex, DataGridViewRow dataGridViewRow)` which can insert a DataRow at particular/desired index.

More details at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/s80x2556.aspx)

[Overloads for Insert Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection.insert.aspx)

Comment: i use this code to add rows between two rows by mouse click     .....private void dgvPDescription_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            
            int current = dgvPDescription.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            MessageBox.Show(current.ToString());
            dgvPDescription.Rows.Insert(current+1, dgvPDescription);
        }unfortunatly i got error ""Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound.""

Comment: @AnoopNarayan well you will have to add that row to your `Datasource` and bind it again